# scrolling doesn't work on IPhone

Tags: ios, css, iphone, scroll, webkit

On all devices scroll works but not working on iPhone

```
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) {
@supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {

body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  -webkit-text-size-adjust:none;
  height: 1300px!important;
  position: relative!important;
  background-image: radial-gradient(circle at center , #0c505f, #053540 );
  color: #0c505f;
  width: 95%!important;
}
```

Comment: For those getting here from a search, make sure you don't have the main wrapper (like #app) as a flex container. This breaks scrolling on iOS/iPadOS. Instead I used `position: fixed;` and it worked, though I'm sure it could be relative or absolute. I also used `height: 100vh; overflow-y: auto;`.

Answer (score 2):

> When you dynamically add content to a div with
>   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; that exceeds the div in height, it becomes broken and unscrollable. You can fix this by constantly having
>   an inner div, that triggers the scrollbar because its 1px higher than
>   the outer div: 
>   - ([Patrick Muff](http://patrickmuff.ch/blog/2014/10/01/how-we-fixed-the-webkit-overflow-scrolling-touch-bug-on-ios/))

```
.outer {
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  /* More properties for a fixed height ... */
}

.inner {
  height: calc(100% + 1px);
}
```

Comment: @alina-bayron was this useful?

Comment: thank you for your answer but it doesn't help me :( what's height do you think I should have?

Comment: @AlinaBayron sorry to hear that. Help me get you the right answer. Can you post minimal HTML so I can replicate this issue?

Comment: Setting height or min-height of inner element does not work.

Comment: Well, finally I found that if we set the touchemove listener of the OUTER to be `e.preventDefault()`，then the INNER scroll will not work.